# Braintree vault not storing payment methods

Tags: ios, ruby, payment-gateway, payment, braintree

My sandbox account doesn't store payment methods for customer in their vault. I am creating a customer object using:

```
def create_customer
  result = Braintree::Customer.create(
    :first_name => params[:first_name],
    :last_name => params[:last_name],
    :email => params[:email],
    :phone => params[:phone]
    )
  if result.success?
    render :json => {'result' => result.customer.id}
  else
    render :json => {'errors' => result.errors}, :status => 400
  end
end
```

and then storing the `customer_id` in my database for later use.

When creating client_token I am sending the same `customer_id` to the API. Here is the code for creating client_token:

```
def client_token
  token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(
    :customer_id => params[:customer_id]
    )
  render :json => {"token" => token}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions about your integration, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/)</sub>

You need to [create a payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/reference/request/payment-method/create) with the nonce you receive back from your client:

```
result = Braintree::PaymentMethod.create(
  :customer_id => "131866",
  :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client
)
```